# Electromechanical locks used in a turnstile

Tags: electromagnetism, rfid

I was looking to build a RFID operated turnstile similar to picture below. I will have RFID readers on both ends where the door would open from either end only if the RFID is authenticated on either end. I was wondering what are the type of locks used in these turnstiles which open the turnstiles when an RFID authenticated and then lock these turnstiles and prevent them from moving after a person enters through the turnstile after successful authentication. Are these special locks or some kind of electromagnetic locks ?

[image: Turnstile I was referring to]

Comment: I don't understand why you expect electrical engineers to answer a question about revolving door locks. What do you want us to answer to the question "Are these special locks"?

Answer (score 4):

Pipe is right: why would you expect us to know? Anyway ...

[image]

*Figure 1. Turnstile mechanism. Source: [AliExpress](http://de.aliexpress.com/item/Economical-Semi-Automatic-Tripod-Turnstile-Solenoid-Mechanism-core-including-a-motor-control-board-tripod-arms/32530388716.html?spm=2114.47010508.4.22.N5e0Su).*

An image search for turnstile mechanism shows up the image in Figure 1.

Without translating the text it appears to be a bidirectional device. Extending the solenoid on the right will unlatch the pawl allowing the mechanism to rotate left. The blue switch probably unlatches the solenoid so that it re-engages 120° later. The other solenoid allows clockwise rotation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flD6sf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Sample turnstile control schematic.*

- Pressing the RELEASE button momentarily energises the relay.
- The first contact latches the relay on.
- The second contact turns the solenoid on.
- The blue switch, when activated, unlatches the relay which drops out the solenoid.